# Transparent objects not truly transparent in viewport in versions >=2.83

Tags: 3d-view, particles, transparency

I've noticed that in Blender 2.83 (and newer) transparent objects in the viewport are not fully transparent in a sense that they:

1. Obscure particle objects inside and behind them
2. Wireframe of objects inside are not visible

This is how a viewport scene looks in 2.82. Notice that the sphere wireframe is fully visible.
[image]

And this is how it looks in 3.3. The particle points inside and behind the cube are not visible, and neither is the sphere's wireframe. I've also tested it with 2.83 and 3.1.2, with the same results.
[image]

I couldn't find any obvious difference in settings between 2.82 and newer. Enabling "In Front" flag of the cube object in 3.3 makes the objects inside the cube visible, however, enabling it for any other object in the scene revers the effect.
[image]

Any ideas how to fix this? Is this behavior expected or could this be a bug in >=2.83?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Why should the cube object be transparent? It looks like your _3D Viewport_ is in _Solid View_, there is no transparency unless you have _X-Ray_ mode enabled, but you don't show the viewport settings in your screenshots. And since the cube is set to _Display As_ > _Textured_ as you can see a little below the _In Front_ checkbox, it is absolutely normal that it obscures objects behind it.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes, the view port is in Solid View with X-Ray disabled and Show Overlays enabled. The objects can be shown as transparent in Solid View by setting the color alpha of the Viewport Display in Material Properties, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NM4LUA6WbA
It works well in 2.82.